# Set checkboxes to checked based on Ajax GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, checkbox

I'm trying to get the checkboxes checked based on data coming from the server through an ajax get request:

---

```
var GetTodos = (function () {
//GET/READ 
   return $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Todos/GetTodos',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (todos) {
            var tbodyEl = $('tbody');
            $.each(todos, function (i, todo) {
                if (!todo.isCompleted)
                    $('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
                else
                    $('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
                tbodyEl.append('\
                    <tr>\
                        <td><input type="checkbox" value="'+todo.id+'" id="myCheckbox" checked/></td>\
                        <td class="id">' + todo.id + '</td>\
                        <td><input type="text" class="name" value="' + todo.text + '"></td>\
                        <td>\
                            <button id="editBtn" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>\
                            <button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>\
                        </td>\
                    </tr>\
                ');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

---

So i'm sending an ajax get request to get json data and the following response is this

---

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Walk the dog",
    "isCompleted": false
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "text": "go out with friends",
    "isCompleted": false
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "text": "touch the fishy",
    "isCompleted": true
  }
]
```

---

This is what I ended up with

---

[image]

---

So the checkboxes doesn't get checked properly. If someone can help me out with this it will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is happening ?

Comment: ID's **must be unique** in an HTML document - how does your code "know" which `myCheckbox` you "mean"? ... oh and `touch the fishy`??? really??

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry about that, http://imgur.com/gallery/ZigXHzX its just something i saw

Comment: You're also (once you fix that issue) setting/clearing the checkbox before it's added to the page - re fishy - nice :p

Comment: `if (!todo.isCompleted)
                    $('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
                else
                    $('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);` could simply be
                    `$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', todo.isCompleted);` - but that is not your issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/27226/)**.

First of all `id` should be unique in same document, so in your case replace id `myCheckbox` by id `myCheckbox[todo.id]`.

And the `checked` true and false the both will check the input you should add attribute `checked` just in case you want to check :

```
$.each(todos, function (i, todo) {
    var checked = '';

    if (todo.isCompleted)
        checked = 'checked';

    tbodyEl.append('\
        <tr>\
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="'+todo.id+'" id="myCheckbox['+todo.id+']" '+checked+'/></td>\
            <td class="id">' + todo.id + '</td>\
            <td><input type="text" class="name" value="' + todo.text + '"></td>\
            <td>\
                <button id="editBtn" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>\
                <button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>\
            </td>\
        </tr>\
    ');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it! your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding checked `attribute` to every checkbox hence each checkbox is checked so just add `checked` attribute to those checkbox only which you need

```
  $.each(todos, function (i, todo) {
            var checkProp="";
            if (todo.isCompleted)
                checkProp="checked='checked'";

            tbodyEl.append('\
                <tr>\
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="'+todo.id+'" id="myCheckbox" '+checkProp+'/></td>\
                    <td class="id">' + todo.id + '</td>\
                    <td><input type="text" class="name" value="' + todo.text + '"></td>\
                    <td>\
                        <button id="editBtn" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>\
                        <button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
            ');
        });
```

Comment: fix the id issue too :p

Comment: append i to id like `id="myCheckbox"+i`